# How to get the position of a specified repeated character in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have this string:

`test (string) (10)`

How can I get the position of the third parenthesis (second opening)?

This one:

[image]

P.S. In real situations I don't control how many characters are inside the parenthesis, so I can't just count them backwards to get a position. I need the index of the third parenthesis wherever it is.

Comment: Should it be an opening parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use indexOf twice, first to get the position of the first closing parentheses, then to get the next opening one:

```js
let s = 'test (string) (10)'
    
let position = s.indexOf('(', s.indexOf(')'))
    
console.log(position)
```

Note that position will be zero-based, add 1 if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression that matches everything up to the third parenthesis, then get its length.

```js
str = 'test (string) (10)';
match = str.match(/^[^(]*\([^)]*\)[^(]*\(/);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[0].length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is definitely not the most performant way.

If performance isn't an issue, I'd personally use `split`.

```
var chunks = "test (string) (10)".split("(")

pos = chunks[0].length + chunks[1].length
```

You may have to add 1 to the formula above or something like that. I don't have time get it just right ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the string contains only opening parenthesis that are matched up with a closing parenthesis, you could use a regex with a negated character class `\([^()]*\)` matching any char other than `(` or `)` in between the parenthesis.

Then get the index of the second match if it is present:

```js
const s = "test (string) (10)";
const result = [...s.matchAll(/\([^()]*\)/g)];

if (undefined !== result[1]) {
  console.log(result[1].index);
}
```

If there can be any unpaired parenthesis, and you just want to match the 3rd one (assuming that using a lookbehind is supported):

```js
const s = "test (string) (10)";
const result = [...s.matchAll(/[()]/g)];

if (undefined !== result[2]) {
  console.log(result[2].index);
}
```